# Is there a better way to create this model? (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model that pings a REST service and saves the results.

```
class StoreStatus(models.Model):
    store = models.OneToOneField(Store)
    status = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.status = get_store_information(self.store.code)
        self.pk = self.store.pk     
        super( StoreStatus, self ).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I need to run it every repeatedly and figure I can just .save() it in a view, since the "Store" object is in the majority of my views.

Is there a better way to do this? I had to the set the pk manually because I was getting duplicate errors when I tried to save a second time.

Seems kind of dirty, and I'm trying to improve my coding.
Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason this model cannot be merged with your `Store` model?

Answer (score 1):

That looks quite bad.

First, associating the retrieval of the status information with the saving of the object is quite a bad idea. If 'updating' is the only action you'll ever perform on this model, then maybe a better idea would be to write a an "update()" method that automatically saves once the status is updated, instead of doing it the other way around.

```
def update(self):
    self.status = get_store_information(self.store.code)
    self.save()
```

Second: how are you creating the first instance of this model? You'll get duplication errors if you are trying to save a new instance every time the model gets updated. Say, if you do something like this:

```
# this will crap out
update = Update(mystore)
update.save()
```

What you should be doing is something like:

```
# this will work (provided we have 'update')
mystore.status.update()
```

Or:

```
# always retrieve the stored instance before saving    
status, created = StoreStatus.objects.get_or_create(store=mystore)
status.update()
```

In case you are lazy enough, you can always add an "update_status" method to your Store model and perform the creation/update there. It's always better to be explicit about what you are doing. Remember: Django is based upon the principle of least surprise, and so should your code! :)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would have created a function that would:
1. Accept the Store object as a parameter,
2. Make the REST call, and 
3. On receiving the response then update the status in the StoreStatus.

This would be desirable to enable loose coupling which is required for architectures involving web-based services.

Moreover, if you just want to avoid duplicate PK errors, you can check for id to safely loop the update and create conditions.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.id:
        # Update case
        pass
    else:
        # New object
        # Process for the new object
        pass

    # Save the changes
    super(StoreStatus, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```